# Как словить Exeption и вызывается ли метод onPause в момент его выброса?

Tags: java, android, java-ee, android-studio, android-sdk

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как словить Exeption? И вызывается ли метод onPause в момент выброса Exeption?

Мне надо в БД инфу записать, я делаю это в onPause каждого активити, чтобы таймером не грузить лишний раз. Но а что если случайно в программе произошел сбой какой-нибудь, можно ли его словить и добавить обработку моего БД, там метод один нужно добавить просто...

Comment: 1. Ищем в гугле по запросу "Java catch exception".    
2. Во время краша (Force Close) приложения onPause не вызыватеся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, при выбросе исключения, onPause() активности не вызывается.

Можно установить собственный обработчик непойманных исключений для всего приложения через *Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler* ([пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129582/)). Но там у вас не будет доступа к несохраненным данным.

Лучше свести к минимуму вероятность появления исключений, обернуть все опасные места в try-catch-finally. Ну и в коммите данных по таймеру, а не в `onPause()`, обычно нет ничего страшного.

Comment: @Алексей Илларионов, нормальный интерфейс, сгодиться)) спс